# Finding the row and column for a string in an array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following array:

```
A = {'E1_02' nan nan nan nan nan;
'Time'  'Force' 'Stress'    'Stroke'    'Ext.1' 'Width1';
'sec' 'N' 'N/mm2'   'mm'    'mm'    'mm'}
```

which gives

```
{'E1_02'}    {[  NaN]}    {[   NaN]}    {[   NaN]}    {[  NaN]}    {[   NaN]}
{'Time' }    {'Force'}    {'Stress'}    {'Stroke'}    {'Ext.1'}    {'Width1'}
{'sec'  }    {'N'    }    {'N/mm2' }    {'mm'    }    {'mm'   }    {'mm'    }
```

This is the start of a very long .csv with data in every column. I would like to find the row and column indices of one of the strings, for example ' Stress', because then I would like to extract the data in that column. I tried *find* but from what I understand it just check if the string is present in a row or column but does not return the indices of the string's location. What I would like is something like

```
What string do you want?: ' Stress'
Search through array...
Here are the coordinates for that string: [row column] = [3 2]
```

Should I make a loop that checks every row and column for the string and then use those as the indices? Or did I misunderstand the way *find* works?

Comment: The [documentation for `find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) pretty clearly states that it returns indices. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

[row, col] = find(strcmp(A,'Stress'))